# Using php variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I've tried to make a javascript inside a PHP page where the page will get redirected to a specific location that is defined by the variable `$url` after a time which is defined with variable `$timer`.

The problem however is that the time variable is not working, it only works when i have a number instead of the variable `$timer`. `$timer` is also defined in the php document from the database.

What is the problem here?? I'm sure that `$timer` is an integer because it is a number.

```js
echo "<script type ='text/javascript'>

 function countdown() {
     location.href = '$url';
  }
  
 setInterval(function() { countdown(); }, $timer );
  </script>";
```

This is only a part of the whole php script! If you want I could post the whole script.

Comment: As a general comment, my unsolicited advice to you is that it is very bad practice to have PHP echoing javascript.  My recommendation would be to look into a templating engine like twig (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Comment: If the `$url` variable is working `$timer` should too. Probably the error is not in the part that you are showing. Are you sure the variable is not empty? What do you see when you look the source code of the page?

Comment: Don't mix PHP and JavaScript. Puppies will die.

Answer (score 0):

`$timer` is a `PHP` variable

```
function countdown() {
     location.href = '$url';
  }

 setInterval(function() { countdown(); }, <?php echo $timer; ?> );
```

Comment: Still no luck :/ Only blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this;

```
echo "<script type ='text/javascript'>
function countdown() {
    location.href = '" . $url . "';
}

setInterval(function() {
    countdown();
}, " . $timer . ");
</script>";
```

Addition: If this doesn't fix the problem and you are sure both `$url` and `$timer` PHP-variables are set, the problem is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: Yea, I think it is from elsewhere because I can't for the sake of chocolate make it work. I'll try with a button instead of timer. Maybe $timer is not recognised as an integer by the javascript. Thanks for answering anyways!